# Why am I counting one less in following code that counts number of elements in linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am unable to figure out why am I counting 1 less in len() function defined below. len() function is supposed to count the number of elements in my linked list.

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* link;
};

typedef struct node node;

node *root=NULL;

void append(void);
int len(void);

int main(void) {

    printf("\nCurrent length of list:\t%d\n",len());
    append();
    printf("\nCurrent length of list:\t%d\n",len());
    append();
    printf("\nCurrent length of list:\t%d\n",len());
    append();
    printf("\nCurrent length of list:\t%d\n",len());

    return 0;
}

void append(void) {

    node *tmp;

    tmp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    printf("\nEnter data value\t\n");
    scanf("%d", &tmp->data);
    tmp->link=NULL;

    if(root==NULL){
        root=tmp;
    }
    else{
        node *ptr=root;

        while(ptr->link!=NULL){
            ptr=ptr->link;
        }
        ptr->link=tmp;
    }
}
int len(void) {
    int cnt=0;

    if(root==NULL)
        return 0;

    node *tmp=root;

    while(tmp->link!=NULL){
        ++cnt;
        tmp=tmp->link;
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

> Current length of list:   0 //  call to len(), Expected output : Correct
>
> Enter data value   20 //  call to append()
>
> Current length of list:   0 // call to len(), Expected output : 1
>
> Enter data value   191 // call to append()
>
> Current length of list:   1 // call to len(), Expected output : 2
>
> Enter data value   22 // call to append()
>
> Current length of list:   2 //  call to len(), Expected output : 3

Comment: This is an excellent candidate for Rubber Duck Debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't count the last element. Try to trace your code.

If your linked list looks as the following

```
elem1 -> elem2 -> elem3 -> NULL
```

You count the elements 1 and 2 but not 3 because the `link` field of 3 is NULL.

Alter your code to the following and it will work

```c
int len(void){
    int cnt=0;

    node *tmp=root;

    while(tmp!=NULL){
        ++cnt;
        tmp=tmp->link;
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: No matter if he doesn't count the first or the last one. He forgot to count one element. It just depends on how you trace the code. 
The changes I've postet will fix the issue regardless of the way of counting.

Comment: can you tell me what does tmp->link mean when I have tmp=NULL ? is it that tmp->link =NULL when tmp = NULL? basically can you tell me what happens when we set a pointer to a structure as NULL?

Comment: If you try to use tmp->link if tmp is null, then you get a strange behavior prior to your operating system, since you try to access memory location 0 (or close to 0). 
However, with the check (`while(tmp!=NULL)`) this cannot happen

Comment: Yes I agree, it would be great if compiler gave error at tmp->link when tmp=NULL, since after noticing, it really doesn't makes sense to me. Your edit worked for me.

Comment: @Abhay you never had a problem with NULL pointer, if you read your implementation you can see that you could never dereference a null pointer, hence no warning.